# Variation of St. Petersburg Paradox

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, paradoxes

I was discussing the the [St. Petersburg paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox#:%7E:text=The%20St.,small%20amount%20to%20the%20participants.) and the following question came up:

Suppose the game doesn't end within nine rounds, then the player directly receives $2^{10}$ dollars , while terminating the game at that moment. What would be the expected value in this example?

My approach:

$$E = [ 2\cdot\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^1+...+2^9\cdot\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^9 ] +2^{10}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^9$$
where the last term is due to the fact that we get $2^{10}$ dollars if the game is not finished after nine rounds which means we got nine times tail for which the probability should be $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^9$.
So in summary we get $E = 11$.

Am I right?

Comment: In a word, yes.

Comment: thank you! :-))